# Add a Data value to the end of an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, if-statement

I need some help with this. 
I am running through some payroll data. 
I have run a function that reads a .txt file, and then stores it in arrays. I am now trying to write a function that allows you to add to those arrays (they are arrays of 32 but only have 20 elements from the file) So it needs to loop through the arrays, make sure they do not go out of bounds, and then add the additional data types to the arrays. Here is how it looks for me. There are no errors, but when i run it, it does nothing:

```
string AddPayrollData(array<double, kMaxSize> &hours, 
array<char, kMaxSize> &pay_type,
array<double, kMaxSize> &pay_rate, 
array<string, kMaxSize> &names,
double hours_worked, char pay_t, double pay_r, string full_name,
int &size )
{

    int i = 0;
    while (size < kMaxSize && i < size)
    {
        if (hours[i] > 168)
        {
            cout << "Hours is out of range, set to 0" << endl;
            hours[i] = 0;
        }
        if (pay_type[i] != 'h' || 's')
        {
            cout << "Incorrect pay type, set to s " << endl;
            pay_type[i] = 's';
        }
        if (pay_rate[i] < 7.25)
        {
            cout << "Pay is less than minimum wage, set to 7.25 " << endl;
            pay_rate[i] = 7.25;
        }
        if (names[i].find(","))
        {}
        else
        {
            cout << "Name Is not in last, first format" << endl;
            names[size] = "unknown";
        }
        i++; 
    }
        if(size >= kMaxSize)
        {
            cout << "Arrays are full, no payroll data added" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            hours_worked = hours[size];
            pay_t = pay_type[size];
            pay_r = pay_rate[size];
            full_name = names[size];
            size++;
        }
    return "";
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You did not show how `AddPayrollData()` is called. Please provide a [mcve]. On a side note, the statements `if (pay_type[i] != 'h' || 's')` and `if (names[i].find(","))` don't do what you think they do.

Comment: May I wonder, why not to use std::vector<T>?

Comment: message1 = AddPayrollData(hours, pay_type, pay_rate, names, 169,
  's', 17.25, "Kerr, Shawn", size);          <<       This is how it is called in the main function. Also, what is a better way to loop through the arrays, check to make sure that each index in the array meets the criteria if it "isnt doing what i think it is"

Comment: @aaronleejackson `if (pay_type[i] != 'h' || 's')` should be `if (pay_type[i] != 'h' && pay_type[i] != 's')` and `if (names[i].find(","))` should be `if (names[i].find(",") != string::npos)`

Comment: @aaronleejackson Got to echo what was said earlier, why aren't you using `vector`?

Comment: This is for an assignment in school and as part of the assignment i cant use vectors, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a few issues here. Some have been dealt with in the comments above. So I will mention the others.

The most important issue is that the purpose of the function is confused. It is both validating the existing data and adding (but not validating) new data. Nothing wrong with either of these things, but they should be separate functions. Or maybe this function should add and validate the new data but leave the existing data alone.

In the validating part, there are some mistakes already mentioned, plus `names[size] = "unknown";` which should be `names[i] = "unknown";`.

In the adding part the problem is that the assignments are performed the wrong way round

```
hours_worked = hours[size];
pay_t = pay_type[size];
pay_r = pay_rate[size];
full_name = names[size];
```

should of course be

```
hours[size] = hours_worked;
pay_type[size] = pay_t;
pay_rate[size] = pay_r;
names[size] = full_name;
```

Finally for some strange reason the function returns a string. Just make it a `void` function.

Comment: awesome. This makes sense. Thanks! Im just trying to figure out the best way to just add the new data and validate it? That is the purpose of this function. The other function i wrote has already validated the old data. As stupid as it sounds, im just tyring to find the best way to add it into the array. Thanks.

Comment: @aaronleejackson If all you want to do is validate the new data then drop the loop in the first part of the function and perform your checks on the variables `hours_worked`, `pay_t`, `pay_r` and `full_name` instead.